# Does the Windows Task Scheduler have a way to run a command a set time after the user logs on?

Tags: windows, login, task-scheduler

Does the Windows Task Scheduler have a way to run a command a set time after the user logs on?

I prefer it to run the first time anybody logs on, whether manually or if the computer is set to logon a particular user automatically.

Comment: ok... the answer is yes. I typed over 15... entering 10. restarted the PC and waited. after 15+minutes had passed I opened and checked the task's history and sure enough 10 minutes after logon it was activated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Windows-7

1. In task scheduler you can create a task.
2. On Triggers tab you click 'New' and from the 'Begin the task' drop down menu choose 'At log on'.
3. Below on the form tick 'Delay task for' check box and choose the delay value.

This should do the job.

Comment: I was looking for something on Windows XP which I should have mentioned, I guess I may have to implement a batch file with a delay in it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a script, you can add a logon script per user or you can add a startup script that would run for all at startup.  This link is for Windows XP  [Local User Account Logon Scripts](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315245) If you indicate your Windows version, more detail can be provided.