# Make computer lock itself after 30 minutes of continued usage

Tags: windows-7, time, blocking

I would like a family computer to lock itself after 30 to 60 minutes of usage, mainly so only my wife can unlock it for those minutes just by entering the password. Is this possible? (I know of how to lock it if idle using power saving and screen saver options. I need for it to lock itself WHILE being used)

Answer (score 0):

To lock the PC you can use the command:

```
rundll32.exe user32.dll, LockWorkStation
```

To make it run 30 minutes after logging in, you can use Windows Task Scheduler to [run command some time after the user logs on](https://superuser.com/questions/376433/does-the-windows-task-scheduler-have-a-way-to-run-a-command-a-set-time-after-the).  Quoted from the article

1. In task scheduler you can create a task.
2. On Triggers tab you click 'New' and from the 'Begin the task' drop down menu choose 'At log on'.
3. Below on the form tick 'Delay task for' check box and choose the delay value.

Combining the two you should able to get your desired results.

Comment: But this would only run at user log on. Is there a way this can be run every time the computer is unlocked?

Comment: @sgarcia You could use a **On workstation unlock** trigger. Here's a complete list: [Triggers](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748841.aspx)